# Implicit function theorem: from local to global

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Suppose that we have $F(x,y)=0$ satisfying the usual hypotheses of the IFT at $(0,0)$, but such that not only $F_y(0,0)\neq 0$, but $F(x,y)=0$ and $F_y(x,y)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U\ni0$, where the open interval $U\subset\mathbb{R}$. Then instead of having only a unique local function $y(x):(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\longrightarrow V'$ such that $F(x,y(x))=0$ for some $V'\subset\mathbb{R}$, we should be able to assert the existence of a unique global function $y^*(x):U\longrightarrow V''$ such that $F(x,y^*(x))=0$. The way I was thinking of this was the following: say we have $y=y_0$, $\varepsilon=\varepsilon_0$ on $(-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$. Then we can consider $F(\varepsilon_0,y_0(\varepsilon_0))=0$, $F_y(\varepsilon_0,y_0(\varepsilon_0))\neq 0$ and find another uniques $y_1:(\varepsilon_0-\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_0+\varepsilon_1)\longrightarrow V'''$ and on the overlap by uniqueness $y_0\equiv y_1$. So defining $y^*$ by cases as $y_0$ on $(\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_0)$ and $y_1$ on $[\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_1)$ we have, repeating this inductively, a $y_*$ globally defined not only on $(-\varepsilon_0,\varepsilon_1)$, but on $U$. However this can be only if the sequence $\varepsilon_i$ does not decrease too fast and the boundary values $y_i(\varepsilon_i)$ satisfy $F_y(\varepsilon_i,y_i(\varepsilon_i))\neq 0$ and $F(\varepsilon_i,y_i(\varepsilon_i))=0$ at each step. The second of these issues is taken care of by the hypothesis that $F(x,y)=0$ for every $x\in U$, since this ensures that if $F(\varepsilon_i,y_i(\varepsilon_i))\neq0$ for some $i$, we have covered the whole of $U$ (I am thinking only about its right half, the reasoning extends symmetrically). My question is: what are usual hypotheses which on the other hand ensure that the $\varepsilon_i$ do not decrease too fast? Are the ones given above already enough? Is it possible to devise one that ensures this? I think perhaps by contradiction one can show that the $\varepsilon_i$ can only stop at the boundary of $U$, since if, say, they converge at some $-u<b<u$, where $U=(-u,u)$ for example. Then one can take $b$ and apply the IFT there, extending the unique solution a little further, against the hypothesis that it could not be done. Is this the right idea? Thank you all for any help.

Comment: What if $F(x,y)=x - \tan^{-1} y$ (where we take the principal arctangent with range $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$) and $U = (-10, 10)$?  To me that looks like it satisfies all your hypotheses, but the solution $y = \tan x$ blows up at $x = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$ so there is no solution on all of $U$.

Comment: It does not satisfy the first hypothesis $F(x,y)=0$ for all $x\in U$. It only satisfies it at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this argument works quite well provided that you insert one minor edit: you should state explicitly that the open set $U$ is an  open **interval** (a connected open subset of the real line.)  Your proof boils down to asserting that the largest connected interval on which the solution exists is both open and relatively closed in $U$. The only nonempty subset of the connected set $U$ that has this topological property is $U$ itself.

As a side note, the argument fails if you attempt to extend the theorem to additional dimensions (with more variables), in which $U$ is a connected open set in Euclidean space of dimension $d>1$. In this multivariable setting, the global form of the theorem can fail if $U$ is not also assumed to be  **simply-connected**. This complication occurred for example when Riemann first attempted to invert many-to-one analytic functions of a complex variable: several local inverses exist  and are well behaved if we avoid certain obstructions (branch points), but the solutions swirl around one another in too complicated a fashion to fit together to yield a single-valued globally smooth answer. Hence the birth of topology and Riemann surfaces.

A three-dimensional example: The helicoid surface that is the "graph" of the multivalued function $ z= \theta =Arctan (y/x) $  can be  constructed by setting  $ F(x,y,z)=x \sin z - y \cos z =0$. It satisfies $F_z\ne 0$ as long as $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.  The removal of this line from ${\mathbb R}^3$ creates a connected open region $U$. However you cannot globally solve for $z$ as a single-valued function of $(x,y)$ on $U$.

[image]

Comment: Yes you are correct, I only wrote 'open' and implicitly assumed interval, since later I explicitly write it of the form $(-u,u)$. Interesting, I did not think about the fact that we would need it simply connected in more dimensions, it is true. Thank you so much for this pointer, I actually wanted to see it through in more dimensions next, and your comments answer that as well. Thank you.

Comment: For a finite open set, like usually in the IFT statement, isn't path connectedness enough though? Say I have a hole in my open set. I could still do the argument and cover it (as long as it is bounded) with balls. Why would the holes bother the argument? Unless I am missing some pathological shape allowed by path connectedness...

Comment: The classic example is the function $w=f(z)= e^z$ in the complex plane, which never attains the value $w=0$. If you try to sequentially  invert $f$ on a collection of balls that are centered on a parametrized circle  $w= e^{ i t}$  that wraps around  $w=0$ you discover that the continuous solution along that path is $z(t)=1+ it$ , which at $t=0$ and $t=2\pi$ disagree.

Comment: Sure, in the complex plane, the exponential is many-to-one but we do not really have that, for real multivariate functions of R^n. I wondered in $R^n$, say $R^2$, as above, with $U$ a bounded open neighbourhood in which we puncture a hole.  Wouldn't following a path of balls covering the whole $U$ (by the same argument by contradiction) yield a global solution $y$ on $U$?

Comment: The complex plane can be identified with $R^2$, the complex exponential being $(x,y)\to (u,v)= (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$. BTW  the typo in my last comment should be corrected to read "solution on the path $z(t)= it$"

Comment: Yes, that is also true (I figured it was a typo no worries), but I do not see how this examples relates to the IFT framework I described in the post. Do you mean $F(x,y)=e^x(\cos y,\sin y)$? Because this is a map from $R^2$ to $R^2$, while I was referring to $R^2$ to $R$. I guess I misunderstood your comment, did you perhaps mean that simply-connectedness is required when also the co-domain of $F$ is also $R^n$ for $n>1$, rather than just $U$ being in $R^n$ for $n>1$?

Comment: I think, if the previous comment I wrote is correct, I get what you mean: your example is essentially about going from polar to Cartesian coordinates, which can be done as application of IFT using $x'=e^x\cos y$ and $y'=e^x\sin y$, thus setting $F(x',y',x,y)=(x'-e^x\cos y, y'-e^x\sin y)$ from $R^4$ to $R^2$. Doing the Jacobian one gets a matrix (-I|J) with $det J=R$ and by IFT we could go back to original coordinates if $R>0$ only. The origin does not have unique representation in polar coordinates. We could go back on simply connected set, not on a punctured neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Yes, I meant the situation when both domain and range space are big.

Comment: It is all clear now, thank you so much for your comments.

Comment: Couldn't resist adding a picture of a simple example!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a different approach will shed a bit more light on the matter: The local  function $\varphi :U \longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which satisfies $F(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow y=\varphi(x)$ and $y_0 = \varphi(x_0)$, is continuously differentiable and alternatively characterized  by the ODE
$$\begin{cases}\varphi'(x) &= - F_x(x,\varphi(x))\cdot (F_y(x,\varphi(x))^{-1}\\
\varphi(x_0) &= y_0. \end{cases}$$

Thus, all the usual theory about ODEs can be used to treat $\varphi$, including the theory about global existence: With steps similar to what you described, the maximal existence interval of $\varphi$ can be extended left and right, as long as there is no "blow-up".

For example, if $F(x,y) = y-\sqrt{1-x^2}$, one has $F_y(x,y) = 1\neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and e.g. $F(0,1)=0$, but the solution to
$$\begin{cases}\varphi'(x) &= -\frac{x}{\varphi(x)}\\ \varphi(0) &=1\end{cases}$$
can not be extended over the interval $x\in (-1,1)$, since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\pm 1} \varphi(x) =  \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\pm 1} \sqrt{1-x^2} = 0$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\pm1} \varphi'(x)$ explodes. For more examples, see e.g. [this short script](http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/asakka/files/2010/02/sec2.4.pdf).

Comment: I like this connection with ODE's. Then you think the hypotheses I gave are sufficient to have a global solution on the open set $U$ (in your example it would be $(-1,1)$).

Comment: @GGG It's important to be precise about the terminology: A "global" solution means that the open set $U$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$. This is of course not the case if the interval is just $(-1,1)$. So in general, even though your hypotheses are fulfilled, the explicit function does not have to exist globally. However, there are some criterions that prevent a blow up, such as for example if the right hand side of $y'(x) = f(x,y(x)$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: By global I only meant on $U$, that is the set on which the hypotheses are satisfied, apologies. That it would not work past $U$, I was taking it as trivial.